# What is the effect of specifying a class name before a argument name in the signature of a function declaration?

Tags: php

Is there any difference between:

```
public function init(a_class_name $classObj)
```

and

```
public function init($classObj)
```

The difference being that example 1 specifies what kind of object I am getting. My question is more: does php still pass the object by reference (Default behavior) or is example 1 some weird shortcut to clone the object. I only ask because in more strict languages (C, Java) example 1 is quite straightforward (and the only example that would work). In PHP it is not as clear, and both methods are used in different places in the PHP docs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's called a a [type hint](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php).

> PHP 5 introduces type hinting. Functions are now able to force parameters to be objects (by specifying the name of the class in the function prototype), interfaces, arrays (since PHP 5.1) or callable (since PHP 5.4).

-- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

In both cases (with and without a type hint) the object is passed by reference. That doesn't change.

Comment: Cool. I assumed it was as simple as that, but it's just weird seeing type hinting in a language notorious for not being type strict :p

Answer (score 1):

a_class_name can be of type **array** or a **class** or **interface** name as far as i know. it just validates the formal parameter given against that rule like instanceof would do.

this functionality is not working with simple types like int, bool, string, ...

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that for the first one, you can only pass an object of type a_class_name to the init method, but for the second one, you can pass any type (int, string...etc)

Comment: int, string and most other simple types won't work in php or are simply ignored and not checked.